# Changing comment delimiter colour

Tags: faces

I am using the following function to change the colour of the comment delimiter.

Whilst the code works for a dark background, the colour is not changed when using a light background.

```
(defun delimkl ()
  "Set comment delimiter colour."

  (if (eq 'dark (frame-parameter nil 'background-mode))
      (set-face-attribute 'font-lock-comment-delimiter-face nil
                            :foreground "#00FF00")

    (set-face-attribute 'font-lock-comment-delimiter-face nil
                          :foreground "#004700") ))
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works in both cases as far as I can tell.